# How to append string values in dynamically created lists using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

Have been trying to append str values in different lists with for loop. Below is my effrot Please help me to figure this out.

```
directors_1 = [] directors_2 = [] directors_3 = [] directors_4 = []
director = dict()

    for director_no in range(0, 4):
        if container.find_all('p')[2].find_all('a', href=True)[director_no]['href'][-11:] == 'adv_li_dr_'+str(director_no):
            director[director_no+1] = (container.find_all('p')[2].find_all('a', href=True)[director_no].text).strip()
            d = director[1]
            "directors_" + str(director_no+1).append(d) #Problem with this line
        else:
            "directors_" + str(director_no+1).append('NA')
```

Comment: short answer: you can't do this and you shouldn't try. use a dictionary

Comment: Append to the actual list variable not to a string representing the name of the variable.

Comment: @PaulH it works with dictionary. But now I have to figure out to create data frame with  dict and list type variables.

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame(my_dictionary_of_lists)`

Comment: I tried with this code but, it only says key error: 1  `directors_ = dict()
directors_[director_no+1].append(director[director_no+1])`